# How to check if the next day is available before the previous day in blade (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to check when the store will be open:

1. if today is Wednesday and the store is close then it will say will
   open on Thursday or Tomorrow.
2. if not Thursday will go to check Friday and so on but the issue is
   it will first check Monday as the number of day is 1.

Then if available the message is the store will open on Monday which is not correct.

So I need to check first the days numbers: 4,5,6,7 then if not available check 1,2,3.

I tried with this but doesn't work.

```
foreach($storedays as $storeday) 
    { 
        if($storeday->storeinfo_id == $item->id)
        { 
           $store_open = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $storeday->open_time)->format('H:i');
           $store_close = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $storeday->close_time)->format('H:i');

            if ($todayTime >= $store_open && $todayTime <= $store_close && ($storeday->available == 1) && ($storeday->day_id == $today)) 
             {
                 $is_open = 1;
                 $when_open = 'now';
                 break;
             } 
            else
             {
                 if(($storeday->available == 1) AND ($storeday->day_id == $today))
                  {
                     $when_open_day = $storeday->day_id;
                     $open_day = date('l', strtotime("Sunday +$when_open_day  days"));
                     $when_open_time = date('h:i a', strtotime($store_open));

                     if($storeday->day_id==$today)
                      {
                          $open_at = 'now';
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          $open_at=date('D', strtotime("Sunday +$when_open_day  days"));
                      }

                      break;
                  } 

                     else if(($storeday->available == 1) AND ($storeday->day_id < $today))
                     {
                         $when_open_day = $storeday->day_id;
                         $open_day = date('l', strtotime("Sunday +$when_open_day  days"));
                                         
                         $when_open_time = date('h:i a', strtotime($store_open));
                         $open_at=date('D', strtotime("Sunday +$when_open_day  days"));
                                         

                         break;
                     }
             }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Is the time relative to the server or to the user?

Comment: didn't get what you mean!!! but for sure for the server time

Comment: convert day to date of week